# Hit a URL as part of a CruiseControl.NET build?

Tags: url, build-automation, cruisecontrol.net

CruiseControl.net newbie question: Following a build/deploy of a website, I'd like to invoke a specific URL on the server. I don't need anything back from the resulting page, just need to request it to make something happen.

I could create an  entry to to fire up IE with the URL as an argument, but I don't want to actually run IE on the server - I just want to invoke the URL.

Is there a Windows shell command to do that? Or, is there a CruiseControl.net-specific way to hit a URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use wget, a command line browser to accomplish this.

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm